# Flash Player - osmf is not working with f4m

Tags: flash, osmf

I created a video player from osmf library. When I stream live video with rtmp link by flash media server eveything is alright. But when I want to use it for http live streaming with f4m link is not working.

How to fix this issu? I can't find any example of this. 
If someone have some example code, don't need to be osmf, with f4m live http streaming player, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using Strobe Media Player.